# I need to use Hexadecimal as the Cases in my Switch statement

Tags: android, arrays, random

So, basically I have two color integer arrays defined in XML.
The first array is set to Random.

```
int[] materialColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.materialColors);
int randomMaterialColor = materialColors[new Random().nextInt(materialColors.length)];
```

I want the Status bar of the application to change accordingly to a darker shade of the color randomly selected.

I have used Switch case for this.

```
switch (randomMaterialColor){

        case R.color.red:

            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.reds));
            break;

        case R.color.pink:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pinks));
            break;

        case R.color.purple:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purples));
            break;

        case R.color.deep_purple:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.deep_purple));
            break;


        case R.color.indigo:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.indigos));
            break;

        case R.color.blue:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blues));
            break;

        case R.color.light_blue:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blues));
            break;

        case R.color.cyan:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cyans));
            break;

        case R.color.teal:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.teal));
            break;

        case R.color.green:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.greens));
            break;

        case R.color.light_green:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_greens));
            break;

        case R.color.lime:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.limes));
            break;

        case R.color.yellow:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellows));
            break;

        case R.color.amber:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ambers));
            break;

        case R.color.deep_orange:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.deep_oranges));
            break;

        case R.color.brown:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.browns));
            break;

        case R.color.gray:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grays));
            break;

        case R.color.blue_gray:
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_grays));
            break;

        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not detect color!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
```

The application is able to run, but the Status bar color fails to change. 
I'm unable to use Hexadecimal values in the Switch case. And  randomMaterialColors is an Integer having that value, but I'm unable to find a workaround.

How can I resolve this?

**Edit [Update]**

Here's the XML file. colors.xml which have the color values of each color in Hexa. These are from Google's Material Guidelines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="red">#F44336</color>
<color name="pink">#E91E63</color>
<color name="purple">#9C27B0</color>
<color name="deep_purple">#673AB7</color>
<color name="indigo">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="blue">#2196F3</color>
<color name="light_blue">#03A9F4</color>
<color name="cyan">#00BCD4</color>
<color name="teal">#009688</color>
<color name="green">#4CAF50</color>
<color name="light_green">#8BC34A</color>
<color name="lime">#CDDC39</color>
<color name="yellow">#FFEB3B</color>
<color name="amber">#FF9800</color>
<color name="deep_orange">#FF5722</color>
<color name="brown">#795548</color>
<color name="gray">#9E9E9E</color>
<color name="blue_gray">#607D8B</color>
<string-array name="materialColors">
<item>@color/red</item>
<item>@color/pink</item>
<item>@color/purple</item>
<item>@color/deep_purple</item>
<item>@color/indigo</item>
<item>@color/blue</item>
<item>@color/light_blue</item>
<item>@color/cyan</item>
<item>@color/teal</item>
<item>@color/green</item>
<item>@color/light_green</item>
<item>@color/lime</item>
<item>@color/yellow</item>
<item>@color/amber</item>
<item>@color/deep_orange</item>
<item>@color/brown</item>
<item>@color/gray</item>
<item>@color/blue_gray</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Why don't you store the random index you're generating, and switch on that?

Comment: The array is declared in XML. Not Java. Can I still do that?

Comment: what you have stored in in this array int[] materialColors in xml? Can you show us?

Comment: Edited. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, you also need to set few flags, other than setting color. Try below code.

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.example_color));
```

Set those flags. This should work.

**[Edit] Update**

So here is the problem. The number **grandomMaterialColor** is **integer** value, and you comparing that integer value with **R.color.red** which has **integer** value for example **21453698789**, which will **never satisfy** the case.

For this purpose you can do one thing. Since you already have list of colors defined in XML and you know exact position of the value in that array. You can modify the switch case as follows.

```
int[] materialColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.rainbow);
Random ranom=new Random();
int randomMaterialColor=ranom.nextInt(materialColors.length-1);

switch (randomMaterialColor){

    case 0:

        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.reds));
        break;

    case 1:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pinks));
        break;

    case 2:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purples));
        break;

    case 3:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.deep_purple));
        break;


    case 4:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.indigos));
        break;

    case 5:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blues));
        break;

    case 6:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blues));
        break;

    case 7:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cyans));
        break;

    case 8:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.teal));
        break;

    case 9:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.greens));
        break;

    case 10:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_greens));
        break;

    case 11:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.limes));
        break;

    case 12:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellows));
        break;

    case 13:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ambers));
        break;

    case 14:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.deep_oranges));
        break;

    case 15:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.browns));
        break;

    case 16:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grays));
        break;

    case 17:
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_grays));
        break;

    default:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not detect color!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

Comment: That's done. The application is able to run, but the Status bar remains Black.

Comment: This works. But now, I'm unable to see a change in the background of the relative layout I'm changing using randomMaterialColors.  This is when the onClick method is called. onCreate works fine.

Comment: When you call setStatusBarColor(), also save the color globally. In onClick() method set the relative layout color to this color.

Answer (score 0):

Parse Color value like

```
Color.parseColor(myColor);//myColor in hexadecimal.
```

It returns integer value.

Comment: I'm already passing an Int into the cases. Where am I supposed to do this?

Comment: at switch value and case values

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different option. Make an additional String array containing all the color names, like red, pink, purple and so on. Then you get a random color name from the array like this:

```
String[] materialColorNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.materialColorNames);
String randomMaterialColorName = materialColors[new Random().nextInt(
    materialColorNames.length)];
```

Now since your status bar colors end with an 's', you can simply do this instead of the whole switch-case:

```
int randomStatusBarColorId = getResources().getIdentifier(
    randomMaterialColorName + "s", "color", getPackageName());
windows.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(randomStatusBarColorId));
```

Comment: However, I have Hexadecimal values in my array which are provided by the Material Design Guidelines. If I use a String array, wouldn't the values be set to their normal colors?

Comment: Uh I meant that independent of your hexadecimal colors. Make an additional array.